# MySQL LEFT JOIN with SUBQUERY is very slow

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

In this query :

```
SELECT tblA.id FROM tblA 
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT invid, max(id) as maxid, group_concat(testcase) as testgrp 
        FROM tblB 
        GROUP BY invid
        ) AS tblC ON tblC.invid = tblA.id 
LEFT JOIN  tblB on tblB.id = tblC.maxid 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY tblA.id
```

subquery is fast but with left join is very slow
How can I make it faster?

Comment: As written, it's also nonsense - as it's exactly equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tbla`. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

By doing a subquery, the result of that subquery is loaded in to memory without any reference to indexes (like primary id or foreign keys, etc.). This way the `ON` statement is done without any index, which is slow.

You should create a query on which you join tblB on tblA, and do your group_concat on the result of both.

I'm not sure what your end result should be based on your example, so I can't provide you a query.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code you could avoid a left join

```
SELECT tblC.id FROM (
        SELECT tblA.id, tblB.invid, max(tblB.id) as maxid, 
              group_concat(tblB.testcase) as testgrp 
        FROM  tblB 
        left  tblB ON  tblA.id  =  tblB.invid
        GROUP BY tblA.id, , tblB.invid
        ) AS tblC 
LEFT JOIN  tblB on tblB.id = tblC.maxid
```

Answer (score 0):

why not without any join:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    (SELECT max(b.id) FROM tblB as b WHERE b.invid = a.id) as maxid,
    (SELECT group_concat(b.testcase) FROM tblB as b WHERE b.invid = a.id) as testgrp 
FROM tblA as a
WHERE 1
```